# Javascript Function with PHP IF

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, get

Hi there I want to ask something very simple , unfortunately I run out of ideas , I want a function when is being $GET to do a JavaScript function straight away, but I just want to make sure that's how you do it...

```html
<script>
function watch()
document.getElementById("home").style.display="none"; 
document.getElementById("watch").style.display="block";
</script> 


<a href="index.php?id=8">8</a>

<?PHP
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
watch ()  <<<ISSUE
//run that function if ittselts GET
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a problem `function function` - cannot call functions using one of the keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line with the issue with:

```
    echo "<script>watch() </script>";
```

Because watch is a Javascript function, and you are calling it like a PHP function.

Answer (score 3):

Is easy, just do the following:

```
<a href="index.php?id=8">8</a>

<script>
var myFunction = function() {  
 ...
};

<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
   echo 'myFunction();';
}
?>
</script>
```

When you receive the id parameter, it will print the code to run the JS function, just put this `<script>` tags just before `</body>` so it can be executed after the DOM has been lodaded.

Comment: If Its That Easy Thanks :)

Comment: Try it, if it works select this as an answer, if not, here i am to help you

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code

1. you cannot name your function "function" since it is a keyword
2. you'll need to echo the JavaScript function call with php so that it is printed on the document sent to client.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use like below:

```
<a href="index.php?id=8">8</a>
 <?PHP
   if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
     echo "<script> myFunction () {
                 ...........
          }
       </script>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Thankyou , I knew this one , I just needed it a bit separate :)